# How to run all enabled tests in a Boost Test Suite

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

How can I run all *enabled unit tests* in a Boost Test Suite? I enable/disable some tests with a decorator.

When I run the test suite with as specifier the test suite name, **all** tests run, including *disabled tests*.

C++ code (`predicate.cpp`):

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE decorator_predicate
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
namespace utf = boost::unit_test;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_suite_1)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(bare_test)
{
  BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(enabled_test,
  * utf::enabled())
{
  BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(disabled_test,
  * utf::disabled())
{
  BOOST_TEST(false);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_suite_2)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(bare_test)
{
  BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(enabled_test,
  * utf::enabled())
{
  BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(disabled_test,
  * utf::disabled())
{
  BOOST_TEST(false);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Output:

```
# Compile the test
g++ predicate.cpp -o predicate

# List all tests
./predicate --list_content
test_suite_1*
    bare_test*
    enabled_test*
    disabled_test 
test_suite_2*
    bare_test*
    enabled_test*
    disabled_test 

# Run the tests that are enabled by default
./predicate
Running 4 test cases...

*** No errors detected

# Here, I would like to only run the enabled tests of test_suite_1.
# Instead, all tests are run. Including the disabled.
./predicate -t test_suite_1
Running 3 test cases...
predicate.cpp(21): error: in "test_suite_1/disabled_test": check false has failed

*** 1 failure is detected in the test module "decorator_predicate"
```

How can I only run the enabled tests of `test_suite_1`?

Comment: Removed my answer because apparently I borked my tests and the results only happened to look ok. It seems there is no way then. Boost Test could really do with better runner interface and documentation.

Comment: I have asked this question on the Boost-Users mailing list: https://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2017/10/88035.php